# AI : find forces to make sum{torque}=0 (for drone maneuver)

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, least-squares

There is a drone with a "hook" in the middle (black circle).

The image below shows top-view of the drone.
[image]

- The hook disables drone movement, but the drone can still rotate in
  every direction.
- I know inertia of the drone in every axis.
- There are many forces exert on the drone :- `a` `b` `c` `d` `e`. 
  (all in z direction, can be negative)
- I can control some forces : `a` `b` `c` `d`.
- I can't control `e`, but I know its value.
- Each force can impact the summation of torque as `torque = r x f`,
  `r` for all forces are known.

### **My objective**

Find algorithm to calculate  `a` `b` `c` `d` to make `sum{torque} = 0`, while minimize summation of square of force  (`a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2`).

Just approximation is enough, i.e. the return result don't have to be real minimum.

In the real situation, there are more than 4 forces that I can control.
The algorithm will be used in automatic-drone-maneuver system in a game.

### **My attempt**

I can split the equation into 3 axis:-

```
torqueX = k1*a + k2*b + k3*c + k4*d + k5 *e = 0             ....(1)
torqueY = k6*a + k7*b + k8*c + k9*d + k10*e = 0             ....(2)
torqueZ = k11*a + k12*b + k13*c + k14*d + k15*e = 0         ....(3)
```

All `k`'s value are known.
I have another objective function.

```
minimize(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)                                   ....(4)
```

After googling, I found that this is **Linearly Constrained Least-Squares Problems** and found an approach to find a precise solution using matrix notation.  ([Ref1] to [Ref3])

I am very new to this kind of problem, but after I skim a bit, I feel that the approach requires inverse matrix computation.

I believe computation around the inverse matrix should be avoided, because there is a risk when the divider near 0.

Thus, I prefer to adjust the force `a` `b` `c` `d` gradually.

### **Question**

- Should this problem be solved by "iteration" approach?
- If I insist, how to solve it using "iteration" approach?
  I found [Ref4], but it seems to be very hard, too hard for a simple (?) problem like this.

### **Reference**

[Ref1] http://stanford.edu/class/ee103/lectures/constrained-least-squares/constrained-least-squares_slides.pdf   (slide 3)
[Ref2] http://stanford.edu/class/ee103/lectures/least-squares/mols_slides.pdf (slide 5)
[Ref3] https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee127a/book/login/l_ols_cls_def.html
[Ref4] http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002437959190009L

Comment: You can also iteratively refine your inverse matrix, search for *rank 1 update* (e.g. [matrixcookbook](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi//matrixcookbook.pdf)) or use [Moore-Penrose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore–Penrose_pseudoinverse#The_iterative_method_of_Ben-Israel_and_Cohen)

Comment: @BeyelerStudios Nice idea!  I forgot that such techniques exist.   Thank for the useful link and a good math book.